# Plug dmix into JACK

Tags: audio, alsa, jack

There are several guides of how to use JACK with ALSA dmix plugin, like [this](http://www.penguinproducer.com/Blog/2011/11/using-multiple-devices-with-jack/) and [this](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Jack_and_Loopback_device_as_Alsa-to-Jack_bridge). All of them suggest to route the JACK output through dmix, which causes a latency to the jackified programs. To avoid it, I've decided to plug dmix into JACK instead. I tried the following .asoundrc:

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "dmixer"
}

pcm.dmixer {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    slave {
        pcm "jack"
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        rate 48000
        format S24_3LE
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

pcm.jack {
    type jack
    playback_ports {
        0 system:playback_1
        1 system:playback_2
    }
    capture_ports {
        0 system:capture_1
        1 system:capture_2
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it, I receive an error.

```
$ aplay test
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:1525:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid type 'jack' for slave PCM

aplay: main:722: audio open error: Invalid argument
```

Is there any way to route dmix output through JACK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dmix` plugin works only with a `hw` plugin as slave.

If you want to mix the output of Jack and other programs, use Jack on top of `dmix`, or consider using PulseAudio.

Comment: OK, I guess it is what PulseAudio was made for.